# How to avoid interface method implementations that needs a pointer receiver?

Tags: interface, go

Consider the following example: http://play.golang.org/p/eAot_sVwND

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Incrementor interface {
    Increment()
}

type Counter struct {
    i int

    Incrementor
}

func (c *Counter) Increment(){
    c.i++
} 

func main() {
    var c Incrementor
    c = &Counter{}
    c.Increment()
    fmt.Println(c)  
}
```

Unfortunatelly I need to `c = &Counter{}` because `Counter.Increment()` implementation has a pointer receiver otherwise `c.Increment()` calls won't be able to modify `c.x` property:

```
func (c Counter) Increment(){
    c.i++ // no errors, but now we increment c.x having a copy of c as context
}
```

How to make original implementation works without `&` on `c = &Counter{}`? In other words, how to avoid the need for the pointer receiver on `C.Increment` implementation at all?

This is just a nit, but I think that maybe a pointer is not necessary to do that in Go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consider defining an `NewCounter` function that encapsulates the initialization of your type (or some 3rd party) and returns a `*Counter`. Usage could look something like this:

```
func main() {
    c := NewCounter()
    c.Increment()
    fmt.Println(c)  
}
```

Comment: Nice, we see this pattern all over the place within go std libs.

Answer (score 4):

> This is just a nit, but I think that maybe a pointer is not necessary to do that in Go.

Considering that Go uses to pass everything by *value*, a pointer receiver is the natural way to achieve what you want.
This is supported by the [Go FAQ](https://golang.org/doc/faq#methods_on_values_or_pointers):

> First, and most important, does the method need to modify the receiver? If it does, the receiver must be a pointer.

You would find a similar conclusion in "[Things I Wish Someone Had Told Me About Golang: pointers](http://openmymind.net/Things-I-Wish-Someone-Had-Told-Me-About-Go/)"

Comment: So there is no way to get rid of the & `&Counter{}` initialization?

Comment: Motive for this concern is that I find it quite unpleasant to initialize structs by reference when using tirhd party packages, so I try to avoid it as much as possible. You end never knowing how to initialize things until you see a compile error.

Comment: @marcioAlmada I understand, but I don't know of a natural way to avoid pointer intialization in Go, when you have a method which modifies its content.